# MySQL: Trigger http request from row-based slave replication

Tags: mysql, triggers, replication, database-administration, udf

We have a row-based replication for which we need the database to send `http requests` to an api on certain data changes.

We know that the `udf library` can be used for sending http requests. But since it's a row based replication, it can't fire a trigger on data changes.

We tried to have the slave replicate to another slave using statement based replication. But it seems that's not possible.

Is there a way that a remote server will be updated in real time, when data changes happen on a row based MySQL replication?